Is the "Interlocked Anything Pattern" from CLR via C# not threadsafe
Reading on the Interlocked Anything Pattern as coined by Jeffrey Richter in CLR via C# 4th Edition he gives the following example demonstrating that we can do more than just Add for Interlocked

Although the Interlocked class doesn’t offer these methods, there is a
well-known pattern that allows you to perform any operation on an
Int32 in an atomic way by using  Interlocked.CompareExchange.

public static Int32 Maximum(ref Int32 target, Int32 value)
{ 
    Int32 currentVal = target, startVal, desiredVal; 
     
    // Don't access target in the loop except in an attempt 
    // to change it because another thread may be touching it 
    do
    { 
        // Record this iteration's starting value 
        startVal = currentVal; 
     
        // Calculate the desired value in terms of startVal and value 
        desiredVal = Math.Max(startVal, value); 
     
        // NOTE: the thread could be preempted here! 
     
        // if (target == startVal) target = desiredVal 
        // Value prior to potential change is returned 
        currentVal = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref target, desiredVal, startVal); 
     
        // If the starting value changed during this iteration, repeat 
    } while (startVal != currentVal); 
     
    // Return the maximum value when this thread tried to set it 
    return desiredVal; 
}

A very similar version of pattern is to be found for the add and remove methods generated by the C# compiler for events:
[CompilerGenerated]
{
    EventHandler eventHandler = this.MyEvent;
    EventHandler eventHandler2;
    do
    {
        eventHandler2 = eventHandler;
        EventHandler value2 = (EventHandler)Delegate.Combine(eventHandler2, value);
        eventHandler = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this.MyEvent, value2, eventHandler2);
    }
    while ((object)eventHandler != eventHandler2);
}

However the one big difference is how we get the "target" value - ref argument vs. field access.
The original example using the ref argument, what is there to prevent the target value from changing before it is assigned to the temp value via:
Int32 currentVal = target, startVal, desiredVal; 

For example by another thread changing the value just as we jump to the beginning of the method?
EDIT: Here is an example of what I mean (LINQPad style)
void Main() {
    var current = 33;
    var otherThread = new Thread(() => MutateLocal(ref current));
    otherThread.Start();
    var result = Maximum(ref current, 55); // at this point current is 33

    current.Dump(); // 100
    result.Dump(); // 100 
}

public static void MutateLocal(ref int target) {
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    target = 100; 
}

public static Int32 Maximum(ref Int32 target, Int32 value) {
    Console.WriteLine(target);
    Thread.Sleep(200);
    Console.WriteLine(target);

    Int32 currentVal = target; // this is atomic...
// ... rest of the Maximum method from above

So Max doesn't seem very atomic when the result of Maximum(ref 33, 55) is 100 which is the stated goal of the pattern.

I am not sure that I understand the question. Are you questioning the correctness of Jeffrey Richter's pattern, or the correctness of the compiler-generated code for attaching event handlers?

@TheodorZoulias the correctness of Jeffrey Richter's code for this case. It is formatted as is in the book.

Nothing stops it from changing before you start the loop or even before you retrieive it the first time, equally nothing stops this.MyEvent from changing. The point is to prevent changes in between retrieving it the first time and the final store, and if there were changes to instead retrieve it again. What exactly is the question? At which possible point could there be pre-emption that would not be detected?

@Charlieface the question is I pass Max(ref 22,55) and before a snapshot is made for the 22, another thread changes it to 100. Then a snapshot is taken for the 100 (doesn't change from that point forward) and the Max(ref 22,55) returns 100.

Tinmanjk any additional information/clarification should be included in the question itself. The comments are intended for asking for clarifications, or suggesting improvements, so that the question is improved. They are neither intended as an addendum to the question, nor as a place to answer the question.

That doesn't matter, the fact is that the Max calculation is done inside the loop, so any changes that happen in between are taken into account. You pass a ref target plus a new possible value, and it makes no difference if any changes happen before the first retrieval. The only thing that matters is that the loop ensures that from first retrieval the value has not changed (otherwise retrieve again).

@TheodorZoulias
it IS in my quesiton
"The original example using the ref argument, what is there to prevent the target value from changing before it is assigned to the temp value via:"
just gave an example for clarification

@Charlieface added a quote from the book in the question which I think doesn't hold + gave an example
"Although the Interlocked class doesn’t offer these methods, there is a
well-known pattern that allows you to perform any operation on an Int32 in an atomic way by using
Interlocked.CompareExchange. "

That statement does hold: you can implement any arbitrary operation using that algorthim and are guaranteed not to get write-skew anomalies. Your perceived issue (another thread modifying before you first read it) is not an issue: any other thread is allowed at any point to run the same algorithm, the only restriction is that the two threads may not clash once the algorithm has begun. You say "the result of Maximum(ref 33, 55) is 100" no that's incorrect. You aren't passing ref 33 you are passing ref target and you want that location to be calculated at some point, ....

.... not its value at the point when you call. The idea being: give the Maximum function a location to work on (not a value), and some calculation to do, and that calculation is guaranteed to be atomic with respect to that location at any given point in time, not to its arbitrary value at the point you made the call. Note that you must use ref, so that you can re-read the exact value at the memory location at any point.

Honestly this question is still in a bad shape. Thankfully Charlieface formatted properly the original messy code, so that we can at least read the code without hurting our eyes, but the accompanying text is equally messy. We are presented with a Maximum method and we are asked about its correctness, without being told what is the purpose of this method, its intended function. How can we tell if it's possible for the method to malfunction, if we don't know what is the proper function? Could you include in the question a description of what this method does, and how it is supposed to behave?

Also this sentence is totally unintelligible to me: "However the one big difference is how we get the "target" value - ref argument vs. field access." Does anyone else have a hard time understanding what this sentence means, or it's just me?

@Charlieface thanks for articulating what the Interlocked pattern is supposed to do, especially:
"... that calculation is guaranteed to be atomic with respect to that location at any given point in time, not to its arbitrary value at the point you made the call."
If you submit it as an answer I'd accept it.

You seem to have a misconception here which you are struggling with.
We don't care if the value of target changed before or after running the loop. We are completely agnostic to that happening, and we are not trying to do Maximum(35, 55), we are trying to do Maximum(ref target, 55).
So all we need to do is retrieve the value of that location at some given point in time, then do some arbitrarily complex calculation on it, and ensure that we store the value back before anyone else has changed it. We simply do not care if any changes happened before or after, we only care that our calculation was atomic with respect to its start and end.
This algorithm guarantees that, as explained in the article:

First take the current value of target and store it in currentVal
We then loop, attempting to make the modification we want, and we continuously loop until we successfully manage to pre-empt both the read and store to target before anyone else.
From this point on, all bets are off regarding pre-emption of other threads, so we need to check the value hasn't changed.
Store what we think is the current value into startVal.
Using the startVal we make some calculation, which we store in desiredVal.
We use Interlocked.CompareExchange to atomically check and possibly store the new value. The value is only stored if the current live value in target is the same as what we thought it was in startVal, in other words we have not been pre-empted.
If we have been pre-empted then the value will be different, so no store happens.
CompareExchange returns that latest live value, which we store back into currentVal. We compare that with startVal to check if it's different, which tells us whether to loop again.

If they are the same then the store was successful and we can go on with our day.
Otherwise we were pre-empted and must loop again.


When we loop, we already have the new live value, we don't need to retrieve it again.

Note that you must use a ref for target, so that we work directly on a memory location. We are passing by reference, so that CompareExchange can directly check the live value of that location.
Also we don't touch target at all within the loop, except in the CompareExchange statement. This is essential: you must use startVal as your working area.

The key point here is the Interlocked.CompareExchange; this is a very well-known pattern, where the code takes a snapshot of the current value, calculates an intended new value, and then uses Interlocked.CompareExchange to perform a conditional update if and only if the target matches our snapshot, i.e. the value hasn't changed. If it has changed, then we repeat everything from first principals, with our updated snapshot of the value. Because of this, the code will not leave this loop until if manages to complete an iteration where the value doesn't change between the snapshot and the update.
Thread safety is complex and you need to specify against what risk code is safe; we can say reliably that this mechanism ensures that we will never get an error due to a conflicting update that goes unobserved - for example, since this is a max operation, we will never go from 7 to 14 despite another thread updating the value to 25 (causing the 25 to be incorrectly discarded). So; thread safety from collisions: yes. However, if we were being pedantic we would have to acknowledge that there is no guarantee how long this might take - in theory it could loop forever if the concurrency gods so wish it - or I guess at most 4 billion times, since it is a 32-bit integer. So from another angle, it is susceptible to collision side effects re performance. In reality, this risk is almost never a real issue, and even looping twice is pretty unlikely in most common use-cases. And when it is a genuine issue, that usually means the competing work is updating too frequently, which can be avoided by having work loops only update the shared token periodically rather than every iteration.

"And when it is a genuine issue, that usually means the competing work is updating too frequently" -- Or our own work is too voluminous. If, for example, we have to make a web request or a database query between reading the state and updating it, the chances that we will be preempted by another thread and have to start all over again are greatly enlarged. This form of synchronization is called optimistic, as opposed to the pessimistic lock, because we are doing work that might go down the drain, and we are optimistic that this won't happen.

Maybe I didn't articulate my point well enough - what happens if the value changes before we take a snapshot of it and doesn't afterwards?
i.e. We call Max(ref 22,55), then before taking a snapshot it ref changes to 100 and the Max is 100.

Many compare-exchange-based algorithms are guaranteed to allow someone to make progress toward the goal.  The only reason a particular thread would need to retry its "increase if under maximum" loop would be that some other thread has made progress.  The only way the loop would fail four billion times would be if some other thread performed four billion successful updates on data items with consecutive values, meaning four billion operations needed to be performed.  Performing four billion unsuccessful operations as well would represent a performance loss, but not a huge one.

@tinmanjk you never passed 22; you passed a reference to the field, which coincidentally happened to have the value 22 at that time, but nobody knows that; the value of it is unobserved until your snapshot. Forget about the 22, it doesn't exist. The purpose was to update the value of the field to a new maximum, if necessary - which we acheived
